# Initializer SKPhysicsBody returns unexpected nil

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Here is the code of physics body that worked year ago but now for some reason not.
Here I create physics body, but it is actually returns nil.

Every element in SKPhysicsBody: texture and size are not nil:

```
 let playerPlaneTexture = atlas.textureNamed("airplane_3ver2_13")
        print("###################")
        print("playerPlaneTexture")
        print(playerPlaneTexture)
        let playerPlane = PlayerPlane(texture: playerPlaneTexture)
        playerPlane.setScale(0.5)
        playerPlane.position = point
        playerPlane.zPosition = 40
        
        print("###################")
        print("playerPlane.size")
        print(playerPlane.size)
        playerPlane.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: playerPlaneTexture, alphaThreshold: 0.5, size: playerPlane.size)

        print("###################")
        print("playerPlane.physicsBody")
        print(playerPlane.physicsBody)
```

Here is the console output where your can see that everything has value but physicsBody:

> ###################
>
> playerPlaneTexture
>
> 'airplane_3ver2_13.png' (300 x 210)
>
> ###################
>
> playerPlane.size
>
> (150.0, 105.0)
>
> 2020-07-25 12:48:36.428596+0500 WarFly[5557:400140] PhysicsBody: Could
> not create physics body.
>
> ###################
>
> playerPlane.physicsBody
>
> nil

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. For some reason alpha threshold now should be lower. So now if I set it to 0.2 for example everything works.